# How can I understand this extract, concerning basic heap overflow?

Tags: linux, file-system

Unfortunately, I dont seem to understand one minor concept in the "Art of Exploitation" book, concerning heap overflow: a new root shell is being added to the passwd file. From [page 168](https://leaksource.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/hacking-the-art-of-exploitation.pdf#page=168):

> However, the nature of this particular heap overflow exploit won’t allow that exact line to be written to `/etc/passwd`, because the string must end with `/etc/passwd`. However, if that filename is merely appended to the end of the entry, the passwd file entry would be incorrect. This can be compensated for with the clever use of a symbolic file link, so the entry can both end with `/etc/passwd` and still be a valid line in the password file. Here’s how it works:
>
> ```
> reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ mkdir /tmp/etc
> reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/etc/passwd
> reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ls -l /tmp/etc/passwd
> lrwxrwxrwx 19 2007-09-09 16:25 /tmp/etc/passwd -> /bin/bash
> ```
>
> Now `/tmp/etc/passwd` points to the login shell /bin/bash. This means that a valid login shell for the password file is also `/tmp/etc/passwd`, making the following a valid password file line:
>
> ```
> myroot:XXq2wKiyI43A2:0:0:me:/root:/tmp/etc/passwd
> ```
>
> The values of this line just need to be slightly modified so that the **portion before *`/etc/passwd`*** is exactly 104 bytes long:

1. I understand the part when the author states that  `/tmp/etc/passwd` can be used to link to `/bin/bash`, but I don't understand how this really works (there is no explanation of `mkdir`, `ln -s` etc)
2. Also, this is probably very simple, but why does the author state that: *"the values of this line just need to be slightly modified so that **the portion
   before `/etc/passwd`** is exactly 104 bytes long"*? Why was `/tmp` omitted in the previous line (i.e. why isn't it stated: "the portion before `/tmp/etc/passwd` is exactly 104 bytes long" ? On the next page, the new root account is written to `/etc/passwd`, but why not to `/tmp/etc/passwd`? I've checked, and there are 2 different `etc` folders on the system; why is this the case?

Comment: Your question will get more attention if you include the excerpt of the text in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation in the actual book (maybe this 'leaksource' site isn't reliable ;-).

1. You type commands: `mkdir /tmp/etc`; `ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/etc/passwd`
2. (A)The heap contains two buffers and 104 bytes is the maximum distance between the first buffer and the datafile allocation buffer. (B)`/tmp` was not omitted, `/etc/passwd` will be appended to the end of the string shown in bold. The last part of that string shown in bold reads `:/root:/tmp`. So when completed with the above it will write …`:/root:/tmp/etc/passwd` to the first buffer and `/etc/passwd` will overrun into the buffer datafile @ 0x804a070 as shown on the next page. (C & D) It won’t write to `/tmp/etc/passwd` because that is only a symbolic link to /bin/bash.

The overall idea is to append the `/etc/passwd` file that has a User ID of 0 so you can be given root privileges. The way this exploit is carried out: “the overflow needing to be the destination file “/etc/passwd” doesn’t allow for us to append the file using `myroot:XXq2wKiyI43A2:0:0:me:/root:/bin/bash` (if we used this as part of the overflow it would write to `/bin/bash`). You are creating `/tmp/etc/` for two reasons:

1. to have an overflow into the datafile allocation buffer of `/etc/passwd` (i.e. the file you want to write to).
2. to have a valid login shell for your entry into password file WITHOUT ruining the target system & actually messing up your whole password file.

[A blog post](http://goffwithblur.blogspot.pe/2011/02/heap-overflow.html) that might help you out. If you aren't familiar with the linux commands like mkdir and ln, let me recommend [CodeAcademy's Command Line Course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line) or a command line [tutorial](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/) out of many you could google.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I was a bit unclear in my initial question, and I've now updated it.  Also, you've stated that: "It won’t write to “/tmp/etc/passwd” because that is only a symbolic link to /etc/passwd." I am quite sure that the former (/tmp/etc/passwd) is a symbolic link to /bin/bash. I think that /tmp was necessary for the creation of this link, but I don't know why or how.

Comment: @RuslanMushkaev, you are correct. Thanks! I changed it to reflect the correct symbolic link. Hopefully, my additional explanation elucidates that you are doing two things at once why using /tmp as a symbolic link as input into the two key buffers.